# Variable scope in a custom object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

I need to access the `buttons` property from the function `enableNav` but my problem is I can't because the `this` reference points to the `enableNav` function rather than the object itself, how do I properly get the `buttons`?

```
(function() {

var MyCustomObject = {

    init: function(config) {
        this.myvar = config.myvar;
        this.buttons = config.buttons;
        this.enableNav();
    },

    enableNav: function() {
       // need to use buttons here!!
    }

};

MyCustomObject.init({
    myVar: 3,
    buttons: $('button')
});
})();
```

Comment: That's just not true: http://jsfiddle.net/KQfj9/ ... maybe you need to wrap this in a ready `$(function(){ });`?

Answer (score 0):

> `this` reference points to the `enableNav` function

No it doesn't.

You call it here:

```
this.enableNav();
```

So inside `enableNav`, `this` will be whatever value `this` has on that line.

(Since, assuming that `new` isn't being used, when you call `foo.bar.baz()` then `baz` gets `bar` for its vale of `this`).

so:

```
enableNav: function() {
   this.buttons.append(foo); // or whatever
}
```